# Javascript dropdown border size and color

Tags: javascript, colors, size, border, getelementbyid

I am working in the CRM and I have created a form. In my form, I have some dropdown lists. How do I change the border size and color using JavaScript? 
To change the color and border for text boxes is easy. The code I have been using is this:

```
function colorchanger(){

document.getElementById("fieldname").style.borderColor="#FF0000";

}
```

I have used this code for all fields that are text boxes and it works absolutely fine. I have googled this problem for an hour but can only find how to change dropdown menus for css and html.
I used this code but it didn't work:

```
document.getElementById().style.border="5px solid #0000ff"
```

Help!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gDf2a/ - this?

Comment: it is working just fine.check it here http://jsfiddle.net/wcLEe/

Comment: I should add what my options are: Green, Yellow, and Red

Answer (score 2):

In order to have a border color, you need a border width.

```
​<select id="fieldname"><option>XX</option></select>

<script>
document.getElementById("fieldname").style.border="5px solid #0000ff";  
</script>
```

Comment: Ya it should work but it doesn't!!!!! I don't know why. Thank you for your help though. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I too face the same problem with the select input. 
By using the below i got it fixed.

```
 $('#selectId').parent().css('border-color','red');
```

Comment: Your answer is related to jquery. Could you also provide a non-jquery solution, to match the question's technologies?